# How to create a git alias to recursively run a command on all submodules?

Tags: linux, git, shell

I have the following command I run manually:

```
$ git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u} && git submodule foreach --recursive "git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u}"
```

I'm using Git v2.13.0. My goals are:

1. Run the specified command on the parent (current) repository first.
2. Execute the same command on all submodules, recursively.

I tried to create an alias to do this like so:

```
[alias]
    run = !f() { \"$@\" && git submodule foreach --recursive \"$@\"; }; f"
```

Which would be run like this (using the earlier example):

```
$ git run "git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u}"
```

However I get the following error (with git trace enabled for diagnostics):

```
09:38:31.170812 git.c:594               trace: exec: 'git-run' 'git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u}'
09:38:31.170899 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'git-run' 'git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u}'
09:38:31.172819 run-command.c:369       trace: run_command: 'f() { "$@" && git submodule foreach --recursive "$@"; }; f' 'git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u}'
09:38:31.173268 run-command.c:228       trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'f() { "$@" && git submodule foreach --recursive "$@"; }; f "$@"' 'f() { "$@" && git submodule foreach --recursive "$@"; }; f' 'git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u}'
f() { "$@" && git submodule foreach --recursive "$@"; }; f: git fetch --all && git reset --hard @{u}: command not found
fatal: While expanding alias 'run': 'f() { "$@" && git submodule foreach --recursive "$@"; }; f': No such file or directory
```

How can I get the alias to work as I want?

Comment: There's an unbalanced double quote showing in your alias above. It should not behave like that, though—it seems as though Git is feeding a repeat of the alias expansion to the shell (as if you ran `f() { ... } f() { ... }`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
[alias]
    # Forcefully perform a git command in the current repo and recursively in all submodules (regardless of exit status).
    # NOTE: The command (after `git run`) must be in quotes
    # Example: git run "git checkout master"
    run = !sh -c '\
        $@ && \
        git submodule foreach --recursive \"$@ || :\" && \
    :' -
```

I tend to just write commands using `!sh -c`. It find that it’s a bit easier for more complicated commands. The tricky part with this approach usually has to do with escaping quote marks and arguments.

On a related note, I really wanted to write an alias that would run a git command recursively like such `git r checkout master`. I tried writing a git alias like:

```
[alias]
    r = !sh -c '\
        git $@ && \
        git submodule foreach --recursive \"git $@ || :\" && \
    :' -
```

This works great for single-argument git commands (like `git r status`), but when trying to run a multi-argument git command, it breaks. For example, running `git r checkout master` results in the following output:

```
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Entering 'submodules/MY_SUBMODULE'
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-submodule: line 360: git checkout: command not found
Stopping at 'submodules/MY_SUBMODULE'; script returned non-zero status.
```

The workaround is to pass in the remaining arguments in a string, like `git r "checkout master"`.